# How to rotate an object by a special axis, without changing the shape

Tags: modeling, mesh, transforms, edit-mode

I want to swing this triangle around on that green axis.

[image]

or some way of accomplishing the same thing.  I just need to flip the triangle on its longest side.  as you can see me attempting to do in this gif animation.

[image]

I haven't found a way of doing it without distorting the shape of the triangle.
and I don't want to just eyeball it by trying to pull the corner into place.
I want it to be exactly the way it was only flipped.